# Typescript can't find module even though definition files are installed

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have followed the below instructions to install lodash into my Ionic 2 project:

http://mhartington.io/post/ionic2-external-libraries/

But I still get the following error when compiling:

> Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash'.

In my code I am importing the module as follows:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

My project can be found here: https://github.com/will093/guess-game

Everything works fine when I run the app, so it is just that the typescript compiler thinks there is no lodash module. The most likely thing that I can think of is that the problem is with my tsconfig file, but as as far as I can see the filesGlob does include my definition files:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "!node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: is there a lodash folder inside your node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes, and the code runs just fine and is able to find lodash. The typescript compiler just thinks that the module isn't there, which should be fixed by including the definition files but for some reason is not.

Comment: looks like the best solution is to copy the contents of index.d.ts of that specific typing to main.d.ts

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gulp-fails-on-type-definitions-added-via-typings-while-vs2015-has-no-problem/52497/4

this helped me resolve my problem with query-string npm package.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the best solution is to copy the contents of index.d.ts of that specific typing to main.d.ts.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gulp-fails-on-type-definitions-added-via-typings-while-vs2015-has-no-problem/52497/4

this helped me resolve my problem with query-string npm package.